# how can i implement two functions for one button onclick in android

Tags: java, android, onclick

Hi am working in bluetooth in android, I have one button click which performs 2 activities.On first click it should perform return air and in 2nd click it should perform reading of setpoint. but in my code only one activity runs and it doesnt go to 2nd activity on 2nd click.In my code there is only one handler to perform this 2 activities. Should i have two handlers to perform this two activities?

here is my code:
This preforms first click:

```
private void returnair() { 
     //return air
     Log.d(TAG, "returnair()");
     setContentView(R.layout.dummy);
     load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             String text = "16 16 36 01 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 47 ";
             sendMessage(text);
         }
     });
     mChatService = new blootoothchatservice(this, mHandler);
     mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}
```

This performs 2nd click:

```
private void setpoint() {
        //reading setpoint
        Log.d(TAG, "setpoint()");
        setContentView(R.layout.dummy); 
        load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 String resp = "16 16 36 07 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B7 93 ";
                 sendsetresponses(resp);
             }
        });
        mChatService = new blootoothchatservice(this, mHandler);
        mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}
```

Comment: didn't you try setting a global variable on each click to know which is the click,1st or 2nd click,on the button?

Comment: From where you calling the two methods?

Comment: in onstart() function this method is called.

Answer (score 7):

How does the application know whether the buttons been clicked once, or twice? You need to store whether that first function has been run, and if it has then run the second one. This logic can be added to once click event like the below pseudo code.

```
global int click = 0;

onClick() {
    if (click == 0) {
        click = 1;
        returnair();
    }
    else
        setpoint();
}
```